# I want to disable the URL and NOTES fields of EKEventEditViewController

Tags: ios, eventkit

I want to customize the EKEventEditViewController with making its URL and NOTES fields disable or removing it. As its the default interface of EKEventEditViewController. I am not able to customize it on myself, I googled a lot for that and can not found any of the feasible solution for this. Any one have worked with such a scenario.Please elaborate the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In header file include <`UINavigationControllerDelegate`> delegate

Set `EKEventEditViewController` delegate to self or YourCurrentView Controller and write UINavigationController delegate method as given below.

```
-(void)performCalendarActivity
{
    NSLog(@"perform calendar activity called ");

    EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    addController.eventStore = eventStore;
    addController.delegate=self;  //<---------------------------------- Must
    EKEvent *event=[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    addController.event=event;

    [self presentViewController:addController animated:YES completion:nil];
    addController.editViewDelegate = self;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]) {

        UITableView *tblView=((UITableViewController*)viewController).tableView;
        tblView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

        //Here you got the tableView now you can change everthing related to tableView.................

        UITableViewCell *cell=[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:5]];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled=false;

        UITableViewCell *cell2=[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:4]];
        cell2.userInteractionEnabled=false;
    }
}
```

If you do not want to show them simply use

```
cell.hidden=YES;
cell2.hidden=YES;
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro. it worked exactly like i wanted it to be .